# jquery hyperlink match

Tags: jquery

I have the following in my Jquery:

```
    $("#lnkpwd").click(function () {
```

I have 2 hyperlinks with the following ids: lnkpwd1 and lnkpwd2

How do I make sure that both of these go to the click.
I know ^ needs to be used but not sure where it would get placed.

Comment: jQuery has good documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ Have a look at these and their descriptions.

Comment: `$("#lnkpwd1, #lnkpwd2").click(function () {`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Description

You should use jQuery's `Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)`

Check out the sample and **[jSFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/vuRYY/)**.

#### Sample

**Html**

```
<a id="lnkpwd1" href="#">Link 1</a>
<a id="lnkpwd2" href="#">Link 2</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#lnkpwd1, #lnkpwd2").click(function () { 
    alert($(this).html() + " Click");
});
```

#### More Information

- **[jSFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/vuRYY/)**
- [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Comment: Yes, the obvious technique, far nicer than an attribute-begins-with selector or a class.

Comment: This wouldn't be nicer if there were 10+ ids.

Comment: Yes of course, but in this case i would maybe suggest another thing. But 10 elements are noch much. This is faster then iterating through all the elements and "find" by a condition.

Answer (score 3):

Select two elements by:

```
$("#lnkpwd1, #lnkpwd2").click(function(){ })
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add a class to both links and make

```
 $("a.myClass").click(function () {
```

or keep your IDs and use this selector:

```
 $('a[id^="lnkpwd"]').click(function () {
```

The last selector matches all links where the ID attribute starts with "lnkpwd".

Answer (score 1):

ID is an attribute like any other. ^= means "Starts with..."

```
$('a[id^="lnkpwd"]')
```